# Executing Instructions on Session Timeout?

Tags: php, session

I'm coding a chat and to raise the list of connected users I just insert the name of the user in a file when he connects and removes it when he disconnects.

The user needs to click on the logout link so the script that is used to remove names from the list can be expressed.
The problem is when the session expires the script is not triggered and the name of the user remains in the file though he is out the chat.

I just want to know if there is a method to trigger a script when the session expires (using apache directives ?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know if there is a method to trigger a script when the session expires (using apache directives ?)

From what I know there is no *Apache Directive* that can trigger a script when the PHP session expires.

From *within* PHP, you can create your own *session save handler* that has a callback for *session garbage collection* which is invoked to remove sessions that are not valid any longer (timeout). Please note that this is not called automagically. Session in PHP is just data that lies somewhere, so it's not actively looking for timeouts.

I think for your chat you need to first think a bit how you do the chat session handling before you start to write code.